# Apache Spark is there a way to auto-format/auto convert datatype to/from known primitive formats?

Tags: apache-spark

In spark 1.4.1 i am getting error while performing join java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.types.UTF8String. Question is is there a way to auto-convert datatype to well know primitives to and fro ?

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.types.UTF8String
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Cast$$anonfun$castToDouble$1$$anonfun$apply$48.apply(Cast.scala:354)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Cast.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$expressions$Cast$$buildCast(Cast.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Cast$$anonfun$castToDouble$1.apply(Cast.scala:354)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Cast.eval(Cast.scala:436)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.InterpretedMutableProjection.apply(Projection.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.InterpretedMutableProjection.apply(Projection.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.HashJoin$$anon$1.fetchNext(HashJoin.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.HashJoin$$anon$1.hasNext(HashJoin.scala:66)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:308)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkPlan.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkPlan.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1767)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1767)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-08-30 16:28:01.172 [WARN]  (task-result-getter-3) TaskSetManager:71  - Lost task 0.0 in stage 27.0 (TID 428, localhost): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.types.UTF8String
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Cast$$anonfun$castToDouble$1$$anonfun$apply$48.apply(Cast.scala:354)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Cast.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$expressions$Cast$$buildCast(Cast.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Cast$$anonfun$castToDouble$1.apply(Cast.scala:354)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Cast.eval(Cast.scala:436)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.InterpretedMutableProjection.apply(Projection.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.InterpretedMutableProjection.apply(Projection.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.HashJoin$$anon$1.fetchNext(HashJoin.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.HashJoin$$anon$1.hasNext(HashJoin.scala:66)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:308)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkPlan.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkPlan.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1767)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1767)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is clear: "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.types.UTF8String" You can´t compare a long field with String field in your SQL statement.

You need to implement a UDF function to compare them.

```
sqlContext.udf().register("string2Long",new UDF1<String, Long>() {
             public Long call(String str) throws Exception {
                return Long.valueOf(str).longValue();
             }
        }, DataTypes.LongType);
```

And then use the function **string2Long(string field)** in your sql statement.

Comment: flagging this as correct ason as this helped me to solve the issue by creating generice methos todo autoconvert.